# 'tostring' function in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create plot name based on input value. However getting error (in line#6).
Below is my code.
Thank you so much for your time and reply.

```
//@version=4
study(title="EMA", shorttitle="ema", overlay=true)
ema_len = input(50, title='Period')
EMA = ema(close, ema_len)
plot_name = 'EMA' + tostring(ema_len)
plot(EMA, title=plot_name)
```

**Error message:**

`Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 6: Cannot call 'plot' with 'title'=string. The argument should be of type: const string`

Answer (score 0):

Const strong means we can’t dynamically change a title. The settings menu isn’t setup to change with user input infront if your eyes. So we just have to choose a name for our plot.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

delete line 5 and just do

```
plot(EMA, title='EMA')
```

in line 6